# Is it possible to use non-retina graphics on retina?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, retina

I got non retina graphics from a graphic designer to use with an app. The splash screen has a resolution of 400x640. And yet I am supposed to make a universal iphone 5 and ipad app using this graphics. It is in a .jpg file.

My question is, is it possible to use such low resolution images (400x640) on a retina iPad which requires 1536x2048 pixel images? Or should I get images of proper resolution?

Comment: the proper resolution is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see on the Apple's developer page that you must meet some graphic requirements for you app. If it's possible to ask for proper resolutions I believe it would be the best.

[You can find more information here to pass it to your graphic designer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

[You can also read here more exactly what is required and what not if you want to get your app in the store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)

Answer (score 1):

The aspect ratios of the images are different for a start.

Also, IIRC, if you don't have a default image that is 568 points tall, then your app will run letterboxed on 4 inch phone screens.

Comment: You think I should ask for proper graphics?